# Perl DBIx::Class: getting the current time from the Database

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbix-class

Here is my problem:

I want to calculate how long ago a record was updated in a DB.

The DB is in PostgreSQL, the update_time field is populated by a trigger that uses `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2)`. The field is inflated to a `DateTime` object by DBIx::Class. I get the current time in my code using `DateTime->now()`

My problem is that when I retrieve the field value, it's off by 1 h (ie it's 1h ahead of `DateTime->now()`). I am in the CET time zone, so 1h ahead of UTC currently.

The right way to solve the problem is likely at the DB level. I have tried to replace `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` with `LOCALTIMESTAMP`, to no avail.

I think actually a more robust solution (ie one that doesn't rely on getting the DB right) would be to get the current time stamp from the DB itself. I really just need the epoch, since that's what I use to compute the difference.

So the question is: is there a simple way to do this: get the current time from the DB using DBIx::Class?

A different way to get the DB and DateTime to agree on what the current time is would also be OK!

Comment: You could just grab the `$dbh` from DBIC and run a quick SQL query.

Comment: yes, that's an option. I was wondering if there was a "standard" way of doing this

Comment: I don't think so. I've written up an answer about using SQL, for completeness' sake.

Comment: Oh hang on, you could include the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a literal piece of SQL in the column list when you build up the resultset.

Comment: `DateTime->now()` should support time zones. If you declared `update_time` as `timestamptz` or `timestamp with time zone`, than no offset subtraction should occur. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` also returns `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: I have tried setting the timezone in DateTime->now(), but it doesn't change the underlying value in seconds, so it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`dbh_do` from your DBIx::Class::Storage](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#dbh_do) to run arbitrary queries. With that, just `SELECT` the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

```
my ( $timestamp ) = $schema->storage->dbh_do(
  sub {
    my ($storage, $dbh) = @_;

    $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
  },
);
```

Comment: nope! It would seem to make sense, but I still get the problem, the 2 times look the same, but their epoch is different: `now: [2017-03-23T14:53:18] updated: [2017-03-23T14:53:18] now->epoch: [1490277198] updated->epoch: [1490280798]
now - updated (in s): -3600`

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend to do all date/time related things on the app server and not rely on the database server(s). Essentially that means to not use a trigger but pass the datetime on insert/update and make it mandatory (NOT NULL).
Besides that you should store datetimes in UTC and convert to your local or other required timezone in your code.
Your issue likely happens because of an incorrect or missing timezone configuartion in which case DateTime defaults to its floating timezone.

Comment: ah the old debate between "do everything in the DB" vs "do everything in the code". The current design keeps only the last update timestamp in the field. So even if it's defined as not nullable, after it's been filled once, then there is no mechanism that ensures that it is properly updated. So I'd rather keep the update at the DB level. And I agree there's something screwed up somewhere in the config of either the DB or my Perl. But what?